# Haskell If Statement Condition

Tags: haskell, if-statement

This is my first time getting into the more "academic" programming languages. Coming from the land of Java/C, I'm having quite some issues with If statements in Haskell. It seems all the examples use a single argument, and a simple gt, ls, or eq for comparisons.

What I'm attempting to do is check if a function's argument is even or odd, then return a value based off that result. This is to speed up the calculation of an exponent, as:

> n^k = (n^(k/2))^2 if k is even
>
> n^k = n * n^(k-1) if k is odd

Here's what I have so far:

```
fastExp1 :: Integer -> Integer
fastExp1 x y =
    if y `mod` 2 = 1
        then x * x^(y-1)
    else if y `mod` 2 = 0
        then (x^(y/2))^2
    else 0
```

I've tried to build it using guarded equations, but I just can't seem to get my head around how to build it:

```
fastExp2 :: Integer -> Integer
fastExp2 x y | (x `mod` 1) = 0     = (x^(y/2))^2
             | (x `mod` 1) = 1     = x * x^(y-1)
             | otherwise = 0
```

In Java, this isn't really any issue:

```
public static int fastExp1 (int x, int y) {
    if (y%2 == 0) {
        // The exponent was even.
        return (int) Math.pow((Math.pow(x,(y/2))), 2);
    } else if (y%2 == 1) {
        // The exponent was odd.
        return (int) Math.pow((x*x), (y-1));
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I can confirm that the Java code works as intended, but with the Haskell I get:

> C:\hello.hs:16:5:
>
> parse error in if statement: missing required then and else clauses
>
> Failed, modules loaded: none.

Comment: Hint 1: why don't you write `if (y%2 = 0) { ... }` in Java? — Hint 2: 1≠0 — Hint 3: there's a reason you need that integer cast in Java. As it stands, you'd need that in Haskell to (though you could well change the algorithm so this woundn't be necessary).

Comment: Is `x \`mod\` 1` a typo?

Comment: The equality operator is `==`, not `=`.

Comment: I mean, why don't you write `if (y%2` **`=`** `0)` in Java? (And I meant 1≠2, not 1≠0.)

Comment: @chepner do you mean `if y 'mod' 2 = 1` should be `if y 'mod' 2 == 1` ?

Comment: Yes. Exactly as in Java, double `==` is an operator for testing equality (computing a boolean value), while single `=` is dedicated syntax (in Java it's for an assignment operation, in Haskell it's for providing a definition).

Comment: Aren't you supposed to call `fastExp1` recursively instead of calling `Math.pow`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments (chepner & Ben), Haskell uses `==` for comparison where as `=` is used for definitions.

For future readers, here is the completed code:

```
fastExp1 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
fastExp1 x y =
    if y `mod` 2 == 1
      then x * x^(y-1)
      else if y `mod` 2 == 0
      then (x^(y `div` 2))^2
    else 0

fastExp2 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
fastExp2 x y | (y `mod` 2 == 0)     = (x^(y `div` 2))^2
             | (y `mod` 2 == 1)     = x * x^(y-1)
             | otherwise = 0
```

As suggested by *leftaroundabout*, fastExp2 can also be done by:

```
fastExp2 x y | (y',0) <- y`divMod`2 = (x^y')^2
             | otherwise = x * x^(y-1)
```

Comment: And here's how it would better be written: ``fastExp2 x y | (y',0) <- y`divMod`2     = (x^y')^2`` `| otherwise = x * x^(y-1)`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I should have formatted that correctly, tell me if I got it wrong.

Comment: In `if`s indentation is semantically irrelevant, and the compiler will be happy with anything. However, for humans, indenting `else 0` the same as the first `if` looks misleading since that is the `else` for the second `if`. I would indent such a chain of `if/then/else` at the same level.